# How to add folder into windows indexing list with windows search api

Tags: c#, windows-search

In Indexing Options, there’s a list of locations in ‘Index these locations’, is there a way to add a folder which created from my app into the list through c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution, anyone who want to let their app folder to support windows search in C# can do like below:

1. Download Windows Search API (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388)
2. Import Micosoft.Search.Interop namespace.
3. write the code

   ```
   Uri path = new Uri(location);

   string indexingPath = path.AbsoluteUri;

   CSearchManager csm = new CSearchManager();
   CSearchCrawlScopeManager manager = csm.GetCatalog("SystemIndex").GetCrawlScopeManager();
   manager.AddUserScopeRule(indexingPath, 1, 1, 0);
   manager.SaveAll();
   ```